# Access 2010 dislikes my .mdb file

Tags: ms-access, office-2010

I apologize for this amateur question: this is my first experience with MSaccess.

When I try to start access 2010 by double-clicking my client's custdb.mdb, access 2010 complains:

Unrecognized database format 'custdb.mdb'

My client says only that "yeah, access 2010 is a problem."

Has anyone any idea what the problem might be and how I can fix it?

Alternatively, can anyone point me to a spot where I can download an earlier version of access, like maybe access2007. The MS download page insists I download Access2010.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've always used MDB viewer for this purpose (http://www.alexnolan.net/software/mdb_viewer_plus.htm)

I then copy the data from that into MS Access 2010. It's a pretty horrible solution but it was the best I could come up with at the time!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a Jet 3 database.  You can see that by opening the file with a hex viewer.  Access 2010 doesn't handle Jet 3.